# Is there an explicit angular momentum in Maxwell equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, angular-momentum, maxwell-equations

Electromagnetism implies special relativity and then the universal constant $c$. And if we set $c=1$, the coupling constant has units of angular momentum (so in relativistic quantum mechanics we divide by $\hbar$ and we get the adimensional coupling $\alpha$).

Question, loose, is: In which explicit ways does this angular momentum appear in the classical formalism? Has it some obvious, useful meaning?

---

Edit: some clarifications from the comments.

More explicitly, I have in mind the following. In classical no relativistic mechanics a circular orbit under, ahem, a central force equilibrates $F = K / r^2$ equal to $F= m v^2 / r$, and then we have $K = m r v^2 = L v.$ Thus when introducing relativity we can expect that the angular momentum for a particle orbiting in a central force will have a limit, the minimum possible value being $L_{min} = K/c$.  Note that this limit does not imply a minimum radius, we also have classically $K = L^2/ mr $, but m can be argued to be the relativistic mass, so when L goes towards its minimum, m increases and the radius of the orbit goes to zero.

More edit: Given that it seems that my derivation of the Sommerfeld bound $L_{min} = K/c$ risks to be wrong, I feel I should point out that failure, it it is, is completely mine. The original derivation of this relativistic (not quantum!) bound appears in section II.1 of *Zur Quantentheorie der Spektrallinien* (pages 45-47 [here](http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/jportal_derivate_00152120/19163561702_ftp.pdf)) and also in Kap 5.2 of his [book](http://www.archive.org/stream/atombauundspekt00sommgoog#page/n9/mode/2up). The usual argument goes about generic ellipses and its stability properties.

Comment: No, electromagnetism does not imply special relativity by itself. The two postulates are independent really. Sure, Maxwell's equations are Lorentz invariant (generally consistent with SR), but that's it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking for here.  Surely you must know that angular momentum appears in classical physics as a consequence of Noethers theorem.  The rotational invariance of the system under consideration (or more generally flat spacetime) implies the existence of a conserved quantity..

Comment: Dear Alejandro, electromagnetism doesn't imply special relativity, as Noldorin says. Also, it's true that the coupling constant has units of angular momentum, but one can also say that the coupling constant has units of action or anything else whose units are $\hbar^n$. The fact that two quantities have the same units doesn't imply that they're the same thing. Especially once you set $c=1$, all quantities have units of $\hbar^M G^N$ where $M,N$ are usually integer. So there are only $5^2$ or so different units - but millions of concepts in the world. Your attempt is a meaningless numerology.

Comment: Dear Lubos et al, I had in mind the example of Sommerfeld definition of the fine structure constant. He first tries to use a mix of special relativity and electromagnetism to get closed orbits around the hidrogen atom. He gets some elipses with a bit of rotation themselves, makes a bit of magic, and concludes that there is a natural limit in the angular momentum of an orbit.The he (not me) defines alpha as a quotient between this relativistic angular momentum of electromagnetism and the planck constant.

Comment: Good point by Lubos. Dimensional analysis can be useful, but can only tell us so much. It should not "guide" theory, certainly, but should instead be used as a "check".

Comment: @Noldorin, please check the edit, I was not guided by dimensional analisis. If you set circular orbits with relativity and try to move $r$ to zero, the speed of the orbit goes to c, the mass goes relativistic to infinity (compensating the zero of $r$), and the angular momentum has a finite limit, $K/c$.

Comment: @arivero F=m*v^2/r does not hold in SR

Comment: This question makes no sense as it stands

Comment: Even with the clarifications, the question makes no sense to me.

Comment: The angular momentum $J$ of the classical electromagnetic field is defined in, for example, in the famous boof by Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics. See also this article: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01921207/document

Answer (score 2):

I think R. [Ohanian](http://jayryablon.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/ohanian-what-is-spin.pdf) gives the answer to the title question.

Comment: I guess that you refer to section 2, but could you do a small abstract of the content??? Also, full reference is better: Am J Phys 54, p 500-505

Comment: Yes, my own "abstract" is the following: if you take a multicomponent field (a solution of a wave equation), it is not surprising that it describes a particle with a spin. It follows from the equations, if they are known. And this spin (angular momentum) looks as connected with the energy flux around z-axis. But the spin value is entirely determined with the number of filed components (spinor range) rather than with a particular energy flux value (the latter disappears after integration and using normalizing condition), so I am skeptic about Ohanian's "explanation" about what determines what.

Comment: Of course, a spinor describes a particle with a spin; it is just a tautology or definition, not an explanation or a proof.

Comment: It seems to me that Ohanian's article does the job.

Comment: It does a lot of the job, and I had accepted the answer if a self-containing explanation had been provided, instead of a pointer. Still, one must be careful about using concept from quantum mechanics, the point was to see where can we go only with maxwell+classical relativistic mechanics.

Comment: Classical relativistic mechanics for a point-like particle does not contain "spin" or intrinsic angular momentum because this possibility was not admitted and implemented at that time. But I am sure there were attempts to add it as an additional equation after discovery of spin and electron magnetic moment.

Comment: Ok Vlad, so here you agree with Lubos in not giving serious meaning to the minimum angular momentum implied by the electromagnetic coupling constant? I never asked for intrinsic, I asked for explicit.

Comment: To me, in CED there is no limitation on the angular momentum because the velocity and other dynamic variables vary continuously, whatever coupling constant is.

Answer (score 2):

In SR with a central force (not gravity) you get from [Born coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_coordinates), or substitution of classical experssion   $v \rightarrow \gamma × v$

$F=k/r^2=m×(\gamma×v)^2/r=L×v× \gamma^2/r^2$

With $c=1$ this gives, $L=k/(v× \gamma^2)=k× (1-v^2)/v$

And the limit of that as $v\rightarrow1$ gives $L=0$ as expected.

Comment: At least a +1 for addressing some part of the question :-) But so your point is that in L= m r v, the velocity and mass are to be taken as no relativistic?

Comment: @arivero L=gamma*m*r*v gives same result, which is what is conserved in SR.

Comment: Well, but which is your take? We have that a version L=F/v allows to recover Sommerfeld bound, and other two versions fail to do it. Probably my "autobahn" to the bound is wrong and one must to do the analysis of trayectory stability as usual, but I would like to know why it is wrong, and which is the right version.

Comment: I have put a pointed to the usual statement of the bound F/c, just for reference. It is true that the derivation is not as simple as I take, but I thought it was due to its generality (not circular traj.)

Comment: Im not really sure what the question is, but if you introduce parts of SR into an argument, you have to introduce all its implications, meaning the entire theory, SR is not a set of independent statements that you can mix into CM, what I have showed is simply that there is no lower bound on either mrv or mrv*gamma in SR for circular orbits in k/r^2 force, but there is a minimum value of mrv*gamma^2.

Comment: That is an accurate statement. Actually, now that I look at it, the argument seems to fill six pages (45 to 50) of Sommerfeld article (eg at http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/jportal_derivate_00152120/19163561702_ftp.pdf ) so it is not trivial to go across all the implications, as you say.

Comment: @kakemosteret Aggh Sorry I was intending to give the bounty to your answer (you *did* more work Vlad, which only quoted a reference), but in the reload the order was changed and I pressed the wrong button